# How to redirect class data into xaml page?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xaml, uwp

I'm getting issue while transferring data from class to `xaml` page, In my console data showing in the class but it doesn't pass to `xaml` page in `UWP`

```
var commonCheckValues = new CommonCheckValues();
     if (!Common.GetCommonCheckVars(commonCheckValues))
         return;
var data = new PrintableReceiptData
       {
          TerminalName = commonCheckValues.Session.TerminalName,
          TableNumber = commonCheckValues.Order.Model.TableName,
         };

Frame frame = new Frame();
      frame.Navigate(typeof(demoProject.Scenario1Basic), data);
      Window.Current.Content = frame;
      Window.Current.Activate();
```

So, it showing data into data variable but when I try to pass as parameter then it doesn't receives value on `Scenario1Basic` page.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Have you get the data in the `OnNavigatedTo` override method?

Comment: I'm not getting any data in on OnNavigatedTo  method.

Comment: protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // I  need data here but I'm not able to get it
       }

Comment: Is there  data in the NavigationEventArgs  parameter field?

Comment: No but i need data in this method??

Comment: Yep, you could get the data from NavigationEventArgs  parameter filed.

Comment: Could you try to move  this line  `frame.Navigate(typeof(demoProject.Scenario1Basic), data)` under  `Window.Current.Content = frame;`?

Comment: yes try but not getting data here.

Comment: Could you set break point on `var data = new PrintableReceiptDataif` and check if has value?

Comment: yes value is here but i need value in Scenario1Basic.cs   page

Comment: I'm getting data in data parameter,So,is there any other way to redirect data from class to xaml page except frame.Navigate(typeof(demoProject.Scenario1Basic), data);

Comment: You could also use [MessageCenter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MessagingCenter.cs#L23)  to redirect  data.

Comment: If the following answer works please consider accept it

Answer (score 0):

> How to redirect class data into xaml page?

When you navigate with parameter, you could get the parameter in the destination page `OnNavigatedTo` method like the follow.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var parameter = e.Parameter;
}
```

You could also redirect data with [`MessagingCenter`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/MessagingCenter.cs#L23) that create base on the publish–subscribe model

**Page1-> Page2**

Page2 need to subscribe Page1 class.

**Page2**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page1, string>(this, "Tag", async (s, arg) =>
{
   await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        textblock.Text = arg;
    });

});
```

**Page1**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Page1, string>(this, "Tag", "string parameter");
```